# Linux command/networking

Tags: command-line, networking

I was just wondering what does this command do in terminal. I am looking for an in depth explanation.

```
sockd IPaddress -j DROP
```

*IPaddress should be replaced by a real IP.

I am using Ubuntu Desktop 15.04. No server, just desktop and my home wifi router.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- SOCKS is a proxy server that allows TCP based application data to relay across the firewall, even if the firewall would block the packets. The SOCKS protocol is independent from application protocols, so it can be used for many services, e.g, WWW, FTP, TELNET, and others.
- `sockd IPaddress -j DROP` , here once your proxy server has received any type/service bases request from the given IP at IPADDRESS field it will drop all the traffic from that IP.

This is similar to

```
iptables -I INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROP
```

In IPTables.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me. Just wanted to ask, may I then for example just view the site when I will perform this command on the site's IP? And another one, what is the IP table? Does it refer to the home LAN router? Because there are not any IP tables in PC's netword identification card. Thx

Comment: Iptables are firewall rules to manage network traffic. By using iptables we can manage traffic dropping ,allowing traffic only from authenticated sources and many more. Just Google for more information.